# Pass views in OnFocusChange in data binding Android

Tags: android

I am trying to pass views using Listener binding in onFocusChange function but get the following error

> The callback android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener#onFocusChange has 2 methods but the lambda defined has 1. It should have either 0 or equal number of parameters.

Please can somebody help me in finding the right way to implement this.

```
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.webage.www.vco_address.User" />

    <variable
        name="obj"
        type="com.webage.www.colin.Validations" />



</data>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:text="@={user.name}"
        android:onFocusChange="@{(view)->obj.saveClick(view, user.name)}" />
```

Validations

```
public class Validations {
    public void saveClick(View view, String name){
        Log.v("saveClick",name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for `saveClick()`.

Comment: Also what is the `<data>` declaration for `obj`? (Edit your question. Don't post a comment with this info.)

Comment: Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that the error message is worded incorrectly. It doesn't make any sense that `onFocusChange()` has two methods since it **is** a method. More likely, the problem is that [`onFocusChange()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html#onFocusChange(android.view.View,%20boolean)) has two **parameters**, a `View` and a `boolean`. You have declared the lambda to take only one parameter. Just add a second parameter to the lambda.

Comment: When I pass a boolean I am not able to fetch value of user.name. Please can you explain how can I fetch the value of user.name.

Comment: @Colin11 The lambda needs to **accept** a boolean value. You can either modify `saveClick()` to take three parameters or ignore the boolean value.

Comment: I have same query with the OnTouchListener , how can we get MotionEvent   object

Comment: @Shubham you should post a new question. Be sure to include enough detail so we can understand what you ate asking.

Answer (score 1):

**for xml**:

```
app:onFocusChangeListener = "@{viewModel::onTargetFocusChanged}"
```

**for program code**:

```
fun onTargetFocusChanged(view: View, hasFocus: Boolean){
        ...
}
```